ValueError: Unable to determine which files to ship inside the wheel using the following heuristics:
MRE
Python 3.9
Windows OS
On running the below command:
pip install kaggle

Complete error message:
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting kaggle
  Using cached kaggle-1.6.15.tar.gz (9.1 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -atplotlib (c:\users\navigat\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -atplotlib (c:\users\navigat\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages)
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [35 lines of output]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\navigat\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\navigat\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\Users\navigat\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\navigat\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-oc6jw0q8\overlay\Lib\site-packages\hatchling\build.py", line 58, in build_wheel
      return os.path.basename(next(builder.build(directory=wheel_directory, versions=['standard'])))
    File "C:\Users\navigat\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-oc6jw0q8\overlay\Lib\site-packages\hatchling\builders\plugin\interface.py", line 155, in build
      artifact = version_api[version](directory, **build_data)
    File "C:\Users\navigat\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-oc6jw0q8\overlay\Lib\site-packages\hatchling\builders\wheel.py", line 475, in build_standard
      for included_file in self.recurse_included_files():
    File "C:\Users\navigat\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-oc6jw0q8\overlay\Lib\site-packages\hatchling\builders\plugin\interface.py", line 176, in recurse_included_files
      yield from self.recurse_selected_project_files()
    File "C:\Users\navigat\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-oc6jw0q8\overlay\Lib\site-packages\hatchling\builders\plugin\interface.py", line 180, in recurse_selected_project_files
      if self.config.only_include:
    File "C:\Users\navigat\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-oc6jw0q8\overlay\Lib\site-packages\hatchling\builders\config.py", line 806, in only_include
      only_include = only_include_config.get('only-include', self.default_only_include()) or self.packages
    File "C:\Users\navigat\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-oc6jw0q8\overlay\Lib\site-packages\hatchling\builders\wheel.py", line 260, in default_only_include
      return self.default_file_selection_options.only_include
    File "c:\program files\python39\lib\functools.py", line 969, in __get__
      val = self.func(instance)
    File "C:\Users\navigat\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-oc6jw0q8\overlay\Lib\site-packages\hatchling\builders\wheel.py", line 248, in default_file_selection_options
      raise ValueError(message)
  ValueError: Unable to determine which files to ship inside the wheel using the following heuristics: https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/plugins/builder/wheel/#default-file-selection
  
  The most likely cause of this is that there is no directory that matches the name of your project (kaggle).
  
  At least one file selection option must be defined in the `tool.hatch.build.targets.wheel` table, see: https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/config/build/
  
  As an example, if you intend to ship a directory named `foo` that resides within a `src` directory located at the root of your project, you can define the following:
  
  [tool.hatch.build.targets.wheel]
  packages = ["src/foo"]
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Encountered error while generating package metadata.

See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Any idea whats going on?

Update:
it is fixed now:
pip install kaggle==1.6.17



Old answer
I am able to successfully install the old version:
pip install kaggle==1.6.14

Looks like there is a issue with the latest version kaggle==1.6.15
Found a related git:
https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api/issues/611

Supposedly now fixed: https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api/issues/611#issuecomment-2249032671

kaggle-1.6.15 version is broken. Better to continue with the previous version for time being.
Downgraded to kaggle=1.6.14 and it works fine for me.

Welcome! This answer is already present. Please refrain from posting duplicate answers. You can comment once you have enough rep. Post an answer when it is different from already existing answers.
